# Eloquent saves multiple models to database by error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I have a controller that creates a new model then passes it to the view

```
public function fill_site_form($id, $step_id, $form_id){
    $form = new FormEntry();
    $form->site_id = $id;
    $form->form_id = $form_id;
    $form->step_id = $step_id;
    $form->entry_json = Form::find($form_id)->form_json;
    $form->save();
    return view('sites.fill_site_form', ['form' => $form]);
}
```

I need it to only create one record in the db but it creates 2 records everytime I go to that route.

I have removed the ->save and then no records are inserted into the DB.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

1. Image of DB entries on the $form->save:
   [SCREENSHOT IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWdGi.png)
2. The DB Schema:

   ```
   Schema::create('form_entries', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->integer('site_id');
       $table->integer('form_id');
       $table->integer('step_id');
       $table->text('entry_json', 600000);
       $table->timestamps();
   });
   ```
3. The code that receives the ajax from the sites.fill_site_form view

   ```
   public function update_site_ajax($id, Request $request){
       $entry = FormEntry::find($id);
       $entry->entry_json = json_encode($request->form_json);
       $entry->save();
       return $request->all();
   }
   ```
4. Front end AJAX code:

   ```
       $('#submit_button').click((e)=>{
           $.ajax({
               type:'PATCH',
               url:'/site/' + document.getElementById('form_id').value,
               data:  {'form_json' : renderer.userData},

               success:function(data){
                   $.notify("Form successfully Updated!",
                       {
                           position:"top center",
                           className: 'success'
                       }
                   );
                   console.log('Response: ', data)
               }

           });
       });
   ```

Comment: Please can you show the contents of your `FormEntity` model? Also, do you have any event listeners set up for the model or any of it relations?

Comment: or are you sending same data from AJAX?

Comment: @RossWilson I have edited the answer to show you the contents and the schema of the FormEntry model! Is that sufficient

Comment: @BILALMALIK That view does post data via ajax, in edit 3 ive added the code that receives the ajax. Although both entries are added on rendering the view

Comment: Check the Laravel Debugbar, look for te ajax call , check if it has been called twice and then check in its details the SQL queries executed to see how much insert took place.

Comment: @elfif Thanks for the awesome tool suggestion!
It shows the query only ran once but still theres two entries in the db.
I tried using FormEntry:create() but it also created two entries.
Ive resorted to using FormEntry: firstOrCreate() which gives me only one entry and its stable. Thanks for the time!

Comment: If you can show your Ajax front end code?

Comment: @BILALMALIK I have added it under edit 4.

Comment: need alot of tracing , probable going through route or somewhere from which the request are going twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it working with Model::create or Model->save, So I resorted to Model::firstOrCreate which looks more stable, still would like to know why only on that model it creates two entries